# How to add custom value to Auth::user() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've some custom value that I want to use in the whole project when the user logs in. I am writing a function in controllers but calling that static method every time can make code little bit lengthy. Instead of calling the function I want to assign a custom value to `Auth::user()` so I can use it anywhere in the project. I tried it below code but it won't work

```
public static function getUserDetailById($id){
      //Do Something  and assign value to $custom_val
      Auth::user()->custom = $custom_val;
}
```

But It's not working in any controller or view. I tried to check custom value in `Auth::user()` but it's missing.

Is there any way to add custom value to `Auth::user()` without adding new column in a table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is very simple. You can create an Accessor for that.

App\User.php

```
public function getCustomAttribute()
{
    return 'Custom attribute';
}
```

Now, you can access it anywhere using:

```
echo Auth::user()->custom;
```

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 4):

Add `custom` to your `User` model `$appends` array.

```
protected $appends = [ 'custom' ];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed to make the extra field available on the frontend.

Comment: How did I miss this? I had it already on my code! Thanks.
Link to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function & accessor on the user model to get different data as per logic-

```
// This method will help you to get complete table data as per need
public function xyz() 
{
    return XyzModel::where('user_id', $this['id'])->first();
}

// Accessor
public function getXyzIdAttribute()
{
     return $this->xyz()->id ?? null;
}
```

Now you can get custom data as well as complete data set of an XYZ Model.

```
Auth::user()->xyz_id; // return the id of xyz_model via accessor

Auth::user()->xyz();
```